# Trouble with CALayer

Tags: ios, xcode, calayer

I have this code and XCode Analyze does not issue any warnings, but in the console every time I get a message:

2012-07-19 23:15:35.122 AttachIt [5725:907] Received memory warning.

Where is my mistake, point it, please.

```
for(int j=0;j<images;j++){
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSInteger currentRow = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k<i;k++)
            currentRow = currentRow + [[assetGroups objectAtIndex:k] numberOfAssets];

        asset = [assets objectAtIndex:j+currentRow];
        float size = [self getRandomNumberBetweenMin:60.0 andMax:65.0];
        CGRect rect;
        if(iPad)
            rect = CGRectMake(10+j*35.5, 75-size, size, size);
        else
            rect = CGRectMake(10+j*26, 75-size, size, size);
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
        temp.frame = rect;
        temp.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        temp.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
        temp.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
        temp.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        temp.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
        temp.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        temp.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        temp.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        [temp setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians([self getRandomNumberBetweenMin:-5 andMax:5]))];
        temp.layer.shouldRasterize = TRUE;
        [albumRow addSubview:temp];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the `images` variable?

Comment: int images; values between 1 and 10

Comment: Right now test this project under XCode 4.5 and no any warnings, but under XCode 4.3.3 i have a warning

Comment: Was before check for ARC compatible: `@interface CollageViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *weak collageView;
}` end after `@interface CollageViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *__weak collageView;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory warnings are not the result of mistakes; they are a normal part of running on iOS. You're allocating a bunch of stuff, so getting a memory warning is not surprising.

If you're having problems where your app is being killed by the system due to excess memory usage, you might consider populating those images over time rather than in a loop. You could accomplish this via an NSOperationQueue or similar mechanism to load the images one at a time.

In any case, you could use the "Allocations" or "Activity Monitor" instruments to see if your memory usage is growing and by how much.

Comment: Thank you. May be you can tell me how i can run function and wait his completition before run next function. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ activity.hidden = false; });` don't work for my situation

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think the code you have above looks fine for small numbers of images. For large numbers, you probably want to be loading the assets on a background thread and then passing them to the UI asynchronously, not blocking on the main thread.